# Limiting metrics at Datadog end

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, datadog

We have an integration setup to send airflow metrics to Datadog. I want to supress those metrics at the destination (Datadog) end inorder to save money. The metrics that I want to filters all have a common word "datagen".

Please suggest how can I achieve this goal.

I cannot limit at the source end as it is managed by another deptt.
The app that sends the logs is residing in kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear whether you are trying to limit the number of metrics or the number of logs. They are very different things in Datadog.

If you are using the Datadog Agent built in Airflow integration, the metrics collected should be included.
https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/airflow/

If the metrics you are collecting are above and beyond those included with the integration, Metrics without limits allows you to control which custom metrics are indexed (charged).
https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/metrics-without-limits/

If you are trying to limit logs retained, you would use an exclusion filter in the Indexing section of Logs>Configuration.
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/indexes#exclusion-filters

Comment: I am trying to limit the logs at the destination (datadog) end. I do not have control of the source (datadog integration configuration). If we try to limit logs that are retained by exclusion filter, can we avoid the charges for those logs.

Comment: Yes, if you exclude them you will only be charged the nominal ingest fee vs. the more expensive index (Retain and Rehydrate) fee. https://www.datadoghq.com/pricing/?product=log-management#log-management

Comment: Sorry for creating the confusion, I am trying to limit metrics and not the logs that have retained.